# ActionMailer - Create new mail with attachments from original RFC822 message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I use an email delivery service to send emails (Sparkpost), and everytime one of these emails is replied, I receive a JSON that contains: the reply mail body as HTML (body_html), the reply mail body as text (body_text) and the original RFC822 (email_rfc822) for the reply message.

After receiving this JSON, I need to forward this email to another recipient. Currently, I use the following mailer to achieve that:

```
class ReplyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def reply(body_html, body_text, options = {})
    mail(to: options[:to], from: options[:from], reply_to: options[:reply_to], subject: options[:subject], skip_premailer: true) do |format|
      format.html { render html: body_html.html_safe } if body_html.present?
      format.text { render plain: body_text } if body_text.present?
    end
  end
end
```

The problem with this approach is that it does not forward the attachments of the original message.

How could change this mailer to also forward all the attachments from the original message (including inline images that are referenced on the html body)?

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet might help you

```
options[:attachments].each do |attachment| 
   attachments[attachment.original_filename] = File.read(attachment.tempfile)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to handle inline attachments

```
 context "Inline Attachments" do
it "accepts an inline attachment" do
  test_email = Mailer.test_email inline_attachments: 1
  @delivery_method.deliver!(test_email)

  images = @delivery_method.data[:content][:inline_images]
  expect(images.length).to eq(1)
  image = images[0]
  expect(image).to include(:name, :type=>"image/png; filename=image_0.png", :data=>"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")
  expect(image[:name]).to match(/.*@.*/)
end
```